# Linq to SQL .DBML Child Property Problem

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a 1:1 relationship between table 'A' and 'B' in my .DBML. The FK in the database is in place and the .DBML diagram shows an association line between 'A' and 'B'. However, I cannot get the code generator to create a child property in the 'A' entity. All I have is the FK column. In the Association properties, I have ChildProperty set to true. However, the code generator will not create the child property. I have dropped and added the two tables several times.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've had similar trouble when a table doesn't have a primary key or LINQ to SQL doesn't like the primary key on my table (for whatever reason).  That might not be the problem here, but it's what comes to mind...

Comment: @shaunmartin - that was the problem. Make this an answer to my question and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The O/R designer will refuse to create an association property if a **primary key is missing** on one of the associated tables.  Make sure all of your associated tables have a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think what you call 1:1 is actually seen by the DBML as 1:* because the list can "have" many of your fk-table, e.g. one empley oyee can have one city, but each city can "have" many employees.

AFAIK a primary key in each table is a prerequisite without which the DBML will not "work". An error is issued when saving it. Your project will compile, but you'll see the errors later. HTH